# How can I use tooltip with Foundation 6?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm loading `jquery.js` and `foundation.min.js` on my page.

I read the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tooltip.html) for tooltip. There, it is written that I need

1. foundation.util.box.js
2. foundation.util.mediaQuery.js
3. foundation.util.triggers.js

for the tooltip, but I didn't find a download link for these files under `foundation.zurb.com`. After some research, I found these files at`https://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundation`. I loaded the required libraries, but the tooltip still does not work for me.

How can I use a tooltip under foundation 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize Foundation, you do not only need to import the scripts, but you also need to bootstrap your foundation elements by placing `$(document).foundation();` in your JavaScript or whenever you have created your DOM.

You could also place it between `<script>` tags in the bottom of your `<body>`